# How can I use behaviours in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to c# and coding in general.

What I got is a weapon script that has a public int of 50 (damage). Then I got another script which is the enemy health.

Now what I want to do is use the value in the weapon script to apply it to the enemy health script and I have no clue how to do it.

I know its something quite simple but ive been bashing my head against the wall trying to figure this thing out.

Please help!

**Weapon.cs**:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    static Animator anim;
    public GameObject hitbox;
    public int damage = 50;
    private AudioSource MyAudioSource;
    private AudioClip WeaponSound;

    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponentInParent<Animator>();
        MyAudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(damage);                 
    }

    void Update () {
        attack();
        block();
    }

    public void attack() {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
            GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(damage);
            anim.SetBool("IsAttacking", true);
            hitbox.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("hit");
            MyAudioSource.PlayOneShot(WeaponSound);
        }
        else {
            anim.SetBool("IsAttacking", false);
            hitbox.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void block() {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")) {
            anim.SetBool("IsBlocking", true);
        }
        else {
            anim.SetBool("IsBlocking", false);
        }
    }
}
```

**EnemyHealth.cs**:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour {

    public int maxHealth = 100;
    private int currentHealth;        
    private Animator animator;

    void Start () {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        other.GetComponent<Weapon>().attack();
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int _damage) {
        currentHealth -= _damage;
        animator.SetTrigger("IsHit");
        if(currentHealth <= 0) {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die() {
        animator.SetBool("Isdead", true);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: show us what have you already tried

Comment: I dont even know how to use this forum. Im that bad. Added the code i think.

Comment: You should read [How To Ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are both instantiated in another main class (meaning ones not isntatiate from another) in c# you just use the '.' operator to access public elements, properties and functions in a class

```
main()
{
    EnemyHealth myehlth = new EnemyHealth();
    Weapon myweapn = new Weapon ();
    myehlth.TakeDamage(myweapn.damage); 
}
```

Here I used the '.' operator to access the public damage in your weapon class and then used the '.' oeprator to pass it to the public TakeDamage function in your health class

Comment: Like I said I am very new to coding so I have no clue what you mean. They are both their own class (separate scripts) and there is no other class etc.

Comment: Ok I like I said I am a super newb so what I did was just: Weapon myweapon = new Weapon(); and then put TakeDamage(myweapon.damage); And it worked!

Comment: Well the three lines of code i provided you will work copy and pasted in. I had assumed you had written the code above. If you don't understand how to copy and paste code then I would really recommend a c# tutorial with a simple "hello world" example because it is too hard to show you how to set up a project on here.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply I made all that code by watching tutorials but im having problems calling stuff from other classes and now Im 100% sure how to do it thanks to your last line of code!

Comment: Ok cool I'm glad it helped. Just fyi on stack overflow, people appreciate upvotes if answers are helpful :-p

Comment: Ill up your vote in an instant but I am unsure how to even do it.. Where is the button? Also just a quick response to your solution. The new thing seems to bother Unity and im trying to solve it with getcomponent. Do you by any chance know how I would solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple! Thanks noone392

```js
main()
{
    
    Weapon myweapn = new Weapon ();
    TakeDamage(myweapn.damage); 
}
```

Comment: Please don't use code snippets for `C#`. They're used for `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScipt`.